# Insert data in postgres partition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, partitioning

I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE full_data (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    name varchar NOT NULL,
    deleted bool NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY LIST (deleted);
```

and its two partitions: active (where deleted = false) and redundant (where deleted = true).

In terms of best practises and performance, is it better to insert new rows to `full_data` or directly to e.g. active table?

Comment: It doesn't matter much from a performance perspective. If you want speed, use prepared statements or ` COPY` (the latter is better).